# DB2 Increment a value by a certain amount

Tags: sql, database, db2, sql-update

I need to write a query that increments a value in a table by 3 when run.

I would like to do something like this but this doesn't work.

`UPDATE table
SET value = (SELECT value
             FROM table
             WHERE condition = true) + 3`
WHERE condition = true

As in the title this is a DB2 database, any ideas?

**EDIT:** Actually this does work, could also do the + 3 in the select. I just had some stuff in the wrong place with the casting I had to do
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is simply

```
UPDATE table SET value = value + 3 WHERE condition = TRUE
```

Does that work?

If you want all rows where condition = true to have (for example) 3+ the max value of any row for which the condition is true, use this:

```
UPDATE table SET value = 
(
    SELECT MAX(value) 
    FROM table WHERE condition = true
) + 3 
WHERE condition = true
```